# How add polyline in mapView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cllocation, polyline

I would insert in my mapview an polyline!
I made it in this way

```
 CLLocationCoordinate2D coord[2];
coord[1].latitude = 45.42207;
coord[1].longitude = 9.123888;
coord[2].latitude = 45.422785;
coord[2].longitude = 9.12377;

MKPolyline *polyline = [[MKPolyline alloc] init];
polyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coord count:2];

[self.mapView addAnnotation:polyline];
```

But don't work and there's this error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
What's it wrong?

Comment: You have to give the latitudes and longitudes starts from index 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord[2];
coord[0].latitude = 45.42207;
coord[0].longitude = 9.123888;
coord[1].latitude = 45.422785;
coord[1].longitude = 9.12377;

MKPolyline *polyline = [[MKPolyline alloc] init];
polyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coord count:2];


- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay {

    MKPolylineView *polyLineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:polyline];
    polyLineView.fillColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    polyLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    polyLineView.lineWidth = 7;
    return polyLineView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Array indices in C start with index 0, not 1:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord[2];
coord[0].latitude = 45.42207;
coord[0].longitude = 9.123888;
coord[1].latitude = 45.422785;
coord[1].longitude = 9.12377;
```

Comment: OK, thanks, Now there isn't error but i don't see the polyline in my mapview... Why?

Comment: @MarcoVelluto: Sorry, but I have no idea. I noticed only the reason for the "bad access" error and assumed that is the only problem.