# Error in drawing polyLine in ios

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkpolyline

I am creating an app, that should display a route between two points.

```
MKPolyline *routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:locations count:2];
[mapView addOverlay:routeLine];
```

The two locations are stored in the array "locations".

I am getting an error

Implicit conversion of Objective-C pointer type 'NSMutableArray *' to C pointer type 'CLLocationCoordinate2D *' requires a bridged cast

Please help me over this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the exact type of the objects stored in the `locations` array?

Comment: Annotations that contains map coordinates.

Comment: After making the changes suggested by the answer, did you also implement the viewForOverlay or rendererForOverlay delegate method?

Comment: No, I am a fresher I dont know, what is that nu

Comment: I highly recommend reading [Apple's Location and Maps Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: I used the code below, no error comes, but nothing happens

Comment: As I said, you also need to implement the viewForOverlay (rendererForOverlay in iOS 7+) method.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16839813/467105 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/15612056/467105 for examples.

Comment: Thank u @AnnaKarenina, but it is creating a an overlay(line), I want draw a path between two points, can U please suggest me something for that,

Comment: For iOS 7, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19772900/is-there-a-way-to-get-directions-in-mkmapview-using-a-built-in-apple-api.  For iOS 6 or earlier, you'll have to get the route coordinates from another source (like Google Directions) but you have to check whether that source allows their data to be displayed on an Apple map.

Comment: But, it is only for ios7, I have to do so that it will support from iOS5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method requires a parameter of type CLLocationCoordinate2D array. You will have to make an array of type CLLocationCoordinate2D. Code will look some kind of this:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D *coordsArray = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * locations.count);

int i = 0;
for (CLLocation *loc in locations) {
    coordsArray[i] = loc.coordinate;
    i++;
}

MKPolyline * routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordsArray 
                        count:locations.count];

free(coordinateArray);

[mapView addOverlay:routeLine];
```

Comment: did you checked coords properly being filled? and ur points have proper values?

Comment: I have plotted the points well using story board, and when I click those annotations it will display its coordinates in the text boxes, so, no problem in plotting the points.

Comment: Actually, I didnt implemented the viewForOverlay method, that's why I got an error.Now I got it. Thank u

Comment: But, Polyline is drawing a straight line between the two points, but I want to draw a path between the two points.

Answer (score 0):

`polylineWithCoordinates:count:` accepts an array of objects of type `CLLocationCoord2D` and count is number of objects in coord. check out this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPolyline_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/MKPolyline/polylineWithCoordinates%3acount%3a). I read your comments below, and it seems like your objects in the array (locations) are of type `MKAnnotations`, while they should be `CLLocationCoord2D`. Have a look into this. Also the error says that one of the objects of this array (which you are providing) contains an object of type `NSMutableArray`. Maybe somewhere, you are adding wrong instances. Have a look at this too.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: What I said is that, location array contains annotation objects, which contains the coordinates

Comment: Yes. But the K-Compiler doesn't understand that. You will need to directly put these coordinates in the array and not the objects(annotation objects) which have coordinates. :P